# Adding a line to a barplot with two different x coordinates in R

Tags: r

I have a barplot and I would like to add a plot in this barplot, but according to different scale values of x-axis I can not do it properly. I would like that the first line cross the first bar and the second line should cross the second and third bars, and the last line cross the fourth and fifth bars. How can I do it in R?
I wrote the following code:

```
   barplot(c(2.5, .5, .5, 3.5, 6), names.arg=c("0-1","1-2", "2-3", "3-4", "4-5"))
   lines(c(1, 2, 3,4 ,5), c(3, .1, .1, 4, 6.5), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit complicated to understand what you want... I will try to help you with these two hints:

1. The x-values at which the bars are plotted are *returned* by the function **barplot**. So, to use them in a latter plot, you can just store them with

   `bp = barplot(...)`

   and use them latter in the call to **lines**:

   `lines(bp, y.data, ...)`
2. You will find that the parts of the lines going above the bars are not plotted, because y values are cropped by default when the view is initialize with **barplot**. There are several possible workarounds:

   `bp = barplot(..., ylim=range(data)+c(-1,1) ) # to set the y-limits during the call to barplot`

   or:

   `lines(..., xpd=T) # to allow drawing in the plot margin`

Finally, a minimal working example is displayed below:

```
data = c(2.5, .5, .5, 3.5, 6)
bp = barplot(data, names.arg=c("0-1","1-2", "2-3", "3-4", "4-5"),
             ylim = range(data)+c(-1,1) )
lines(bp, c(3, .1, .1, 4, 6.5), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

[image]